# How to use unpivot() for deferent data type columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

In table1 ,data type of columns are as follows,

```
category1 VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
category2 VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
category3 NUMBER
```

I want to make a view by using `unpivot()` to make all category1,category2 and category3 to under category column.

```
select
ID,
CATEGORY,   
REASON  
from  table1  
 unpivot(
        REASON for CATEGORY in(catgory1,category2,category3)
        );
```

when I'm trying to execute this query it shows following error,

> **expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression**

Comment: can you add sample data and expected output

Comment: Change the datatype of category 3 to VARCHAR(20)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its because category3 is NUMERIC datatype in your table so change its to Varchar or Char.

```
        select
        ID,
        CATEGORY,   
        REASON  
        from 
        (
        select  
        ID,
        category1,category2,TO_CHAR(category3)category3
        from table1  
        )a
        unpivot(
                REASON for CATEGORY in(category1,category2,category3)
                )
```